# Easy building a dictionary of dictionaries or dictionaries of

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

With python3, I must build a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries of ... of lists.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do what the code below does (it looks like garbage code...)

```
ret = {}
for r in listOfDictionariesFromMongoDatabase:
    a = TheObjectIUse(r)
    sp = a.getSp()
    ex = a.getEx()
    th = a.getTh()
    lo = a.getLo()
    de = a.getDe()
    if not sp in ret:
        ret[sp] = {}
    if not ex in ret[sp]:
        ret[sp][ex] = {}
    if not th in ret[sp][ex]:
        ret[sp][ex][th] = {}
    if not lo in ret[sp][ex][th]:
        ret[sp][ex][th][lo] = []
    ret[sp][ex][th][lo].append(de)
```

Comment: Yes. [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing a page from ["One-line Tree in Python"](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250), you can create an recursively-defined `defaultdict`:

```
# UNTESTED

from collections import defaultdict
def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)
def tree_as_dict(t):
    try:
        return {k:tree_as_dict(v) for k,v in t.items()}
    except AttributeError:
        return t

ret = tree()
for r in listOfDictionnariesFromMongoDatabase:
    a = TheObjectIUse(r)
    sp = a.getSp()
    ex = a.getEx()
    th = a.getTh()
    lo = a.getLo()
    de = a.getDe()
    ret[sp][ex][th].setdefault(lo, []).append(de)
return tree_as_dict(ret)
```

Of course, any solution that involves `defaultdict` can be rewritten to use `dict.setdefault`, and vice-versa:

```
# UNTESTED
ret = {}
for r in listOfDictionnariesFromMongoDatabase:
    a = TheObjectIUse(r)
    sp = a.getSp()
    ex = a.getEx()
    th = a.getTh()
    lo = a.getLo()
    de = a.getDe()

    d = ret.setdefault(sp, {})
    d = d.setdefault(ex, {})
    d = d.setdefault(th, {})
    l = d.setdefault(lo, [])
    l.append(de)
return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to make a complex data structure. I recommend using just a simple dictionary with keys that is tuple. So, each key is a tuple of multiple keys and each element can be accesses just by using appropriate tuple key.

```
ret = {}
for r in listOfDictionnariesFromMongoDatabase:
    a = TheObjectIUse(r)
    sp = a.getSp()
    ex = a.getEx()
    th = a.getTh()
    lo = a.getLo()
    de = a.getDe()

    tuple_key = (sp, ex, th, lo)
    if tuple_key not in ret:
        ret[tuple_key] = []
    ret[tuple_key].append(de)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the practice depends also on the context ... which you don't have. Also, I don't see why a complex structure is a bad practice!
Sometimes, for good reasons, a good practice is to not follow good practices. There's the rule, and the spirit of the rule.